# Looping over a list of objects in Python, reference/assignment works unexpectedly

Tags: python, loops, variable-assignment

I have some code that does what I need it to, but I expect it not to. I expect it should be broken, but it works.

I am trying to keep find and keep track of a the best* instance from a list of objects, and am assigning the variable `best_sucessor_state` to the variable `successor_state` each time I find a `successor_state` which is better* than the current `best_sucessor_state`.

With each loop of the for loop, the variable `successor_state` is assigned(?) to a new `state` instance from the list of `state` objects generated by `current_state.successor_states()`

Since I am assigning(?) `best_sucessor_state` to the variable `successor_state`, I do not understand why the underlying state to which `best_successor_state` is assigned(?) does not update each time the for-loop loops and the variable `successor state` is assigned(?) to a new `state` from the `current_state.successor_states()` list.

If someone could explain the following I would be very grateful:

1. Why this is the case?
2. If I wanted to break my code and have `best_successor_state` stay up to date with the changes of `successor_state` as the loop loops, how could I do this?
3. What is the accurate language ("assignment/referencing", "variable/label/name") that I should be using?

***best**: The `state` class has a method to calculate the value, which is called `objective_function`, the lower the better

Here's the code, many thanks:

```
def steepest_ascent_HCS(initial_state, objective_function):

    current_state = initial_state

    while True:
        current_state_value = objective_function(current_state)
        best_successor_state_value = float('inf')

        for successor_state in current_state.successor_states():
            successor_state_value = objective_function(successor_state)

            if successor_state_value < best_successor_state_value:
                best_successor_state = successor_state
                best_successor_state_value = successor_state_value

        if best_successor_state_value >= current_state_value:
                return current_state, current_state_value

        current_state = best_successor_state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer is that python variables are like C pointers (if you are familiar with C), and your code is performing exactly as would be expected. To go through your questions in detail:

1. When you write `x = 1` in python you are saying that the variable `x` should point to the bit of memory storing the value of `1`. If you then write `y = x` you are saying `y` should point to the bit of memory storing the value of `x`, which is found by looking at the bit of memory pointed to by `x`. For all intents and purposes these two variables are the same now, and modifying the state of one will modify the state of the other. However if you then wrote `x = 4`, then you are asking for `x` to point to the memory storing the value of `4` and `y` is still pointing to it's previous value of `1`.

   The way this affects your program is that when you write `best_successor_state = successor_state` you are asking `best_successor_state` to point to the value of `successor_state` which is found by looking at the value `successor_state` points to. So after this statement the two variables are effectively the same thing. Then when you reach the `for successor_state in current_state.successor_states():` you are effectively calling `successor_state = <SOME_OTHER_STATE>`. Now `best_successor_state` is pointing to the value that `successor_state` used to have and `successor_state` is pointing to the new state; once again they are no longer equivalent objects.
2. What you are asking here is for `successor_state` and `best_successor_state` to be the same object at all times. The only way I see to do this is to replace `for successor_state in current_state.successor_sates():` with somethings silly like `for best_successor_state in current_state.successor_states():`.
3. You assign a variable when ever you have something of the form `x = y`. You reference a variable whenever you are looking at it's value, so in `x = y` you are referencing `y`. Variable is used to mean a value that you can manipulate in a program, and I would definitely use that over label or name (you might say that "x" is the label for variable `x`, but that is getting somewhat into semantics).

Comment: Thanks Jake. I suppose my prior incorrect mental model was that the variables are daisy chained together back to the original object, i.e. `a` points to `b` which points to `c` (where `a` and `b` are variables, and `c` is an object). However as you explain, when assigning a variable to an existing variable, you actually end up with something more like `a` points to `c` and `b` points to `c`.

Comment: Yep, that about sums it up.

Answer (score 1):

> Why this is the case?

This happens because each time you go through the loop, `successor_state` becomes a label to a different object created by `current_state.successor_states()`. When you then assign `best_successor_state`, you are creating a label to that specific `successor_state` object (i.e. the address in memory where that `successor_state` is pointing, and not the `successor_state` label itself). It will be clear if you run this code (`id` gives you the memory address of the object, at least in CPython):

```
max_value = 0
for index in [1, 3, 2]:
    print("Current index id: ", id(index))
    if max_value < index:
        max_value = index
    print("Maximum index id: ", id(max_value))
```

When `index` goes from 3 to 2, `max_value` keeps pointing to the previous id of `index`. It is pointing to that id and not to "whatever `index` points to at the moment".

> If I wanted to break my code and have best_successor_state stay up to
>   date with the changes of successor_state as the loop loops, how could
>   I do this?

You could do something like that pointing to an object:

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
m = a
for i in range(3):
    a.x = i
    print(m.x)
```

You'll see that `m.x` gets the value from `a.x` even though we are not changing it directly.

Regarding your last question, it is relevant in this context, because it really revolves about entities being labels and not references, but I am not an expert in those finer details to give you a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. The example you gave is useful for thinking about what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking why doesn't the best_successor_state value change with every iteration of the for loop.
the answer is simply because that's how you wrote it (and it should work correctly for your local search).

```
          if successor_state_value < best_successor_state_value:
```

this line makes sure the best_successor_state is assigned to the successor state only if that's the case i.e. the new state is actually better than your current best successor.
bearing that in mind, to answer your second question your code is updating your best successor already if needed.
I don't understand the third part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't fully understand what it is that you don't understand. As far as I can tell this code works (you already figured that out, but I mean the behaviour you're describing matches what this code is supposed to do). You say "Since I am assigning(?) best_sucessor_state to the variable successor_state [...]" I don't know if that's just confusion regarding the language but it's actually the other way around: you're assigning `successor_state` to the variable `best_successor_state` this happens every iteration of the loop **if** this iteration's `successor_state_value` is less than the current `best_successor_state_value`
2. If you want `best_successor_state` to update every iteration of the loop you'd simply remove the `if`-statement but that would mean that by the end of the `for`-loop `best_successor_state` would just be equal to the last value in `current_state.successor_states()`
3. Assigning a value to a variable. In `best_successor_state = successor_state` you're assigning the value `successor_state` to the variable `best_successor_state`.